# Slider dots move when changing position in CSS

Tags: css, slider

I got a CSS3 slider that works, but I want the points at the bottom by which you can navigate slides to be positioned inside the slider itself.

When I change the position of the dots they stop working, if I click a dot it doesn't navigate to that slide and it makes a weird hop.

Anybody know how I can change the position of the dots while retaining it's function?

Thanks

I added a jsfiddle to demonstrate what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/98LLpmc3/11/

In the fiddle the slider works as it should, but the dots are not inside the slider.

When I change it so that the dots fall in the slider like this:

```
#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):active {
    bottom: 15px
}
```

It stops working.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):not(.show-description-label) {
    ...
    bottom: -44px;
    ...
}
```

To

```
#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):not(.show-description-label) {
    ...
    bottom: 15px;
    ...
}
```

And

```
#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):active {
    bottom: -46px
}
```

To

```
#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):active {
    bottom: 15px
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/98LLpmc3/14/)